# How to use Flutter (web app) stream builder with Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I see several questions and answers about Flutter for mobile that use stream builder like this:

```
body: new StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("collection").snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    ...
```

I'm trying to do the same on flutter for the web, but in my configuration, the `snapshots()` method is unknown, generating an exception while running (and a vscode warning beforehand).  Why? Do I have an incorrect setup?

I've followed these steps which I found here and elsewhere:

1) Included firebase as a dependency in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase: ^6.0.0
```

2) Included the firestore js scripts in the index.html body tag:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

3) In main.dart, imported firebase.dart files (using advice given [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart), though I'm not exactly sure which step above got me access to this package.  I'm a flutter nube, if it isn't obvious)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
import 'package:firebase/firestore.dart' as fs;
```

Having followed these steps, I can get this code working....

```
void main() {
  if (fb.apps.length == 0) {
    try {
      fb.initializeApp(
        apiKey: "mike",
        authDomain: "myauthdomain",
        databaseURL: "mydburl",
        projectId: "myproductid",
        storageBucket: "mystoragebucket",
      );
    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  fs.Firestore store = fb.firestore();
  fs.CollectionReference ref = store.collection("MyCollection");
  ref.onSnapshot.listen((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      print(doc.data());  // this works!!
    });
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

But, as I mentioned earlier, getting the stream builder working, all of the advice suggests that I can get a stream of snapshots by saying...

```
class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder(
      stream: fb.firestore().collection('MyCollection').snapshots(),
      ...
```

The packages I have running on web don't seem to have anything like the `snapshots` method (or property) on a firestore collection reference. Can somebody set me straight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when I tried to create a web version of my flutter mobile app which uses a lot of `StreamBuilders`. The following works for me:

Pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```
  firebase_web: ^5.0.9
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+2
```

In your code:

```
import 'package:firebase_web/firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_web/firebase.dart';

body: new StreamBuilder(
  stream: firestore().collection('collection').onSnapshot,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
...
```

Below I have included a list with changes that I encountered so far going from a flutter mobile app to a flutter web app:

- `documents` = `docs` as in `snapshot.data.docs.length`
- `documents()` = `doc()` as in `firestore().collection('foo').doc('bar')`
- `reference` = `ref` as in `snapshot.ref`
- `data` = `data()` as in `snapshot.data()`
- The method `setData` from Firestore = `set`
- The method `updateData` from Firestore = `update(data:{'yourKey': 'yourValue',})`

Hope this can help!

Comment: I haven't actually tried this to see if it works, and I may not try it. I decided to abandon flutter for www until google actually (really) supports it.  In the meantime, let's assume this works, and thanks.

Comment: @Lorence, I can't get your method to work... what am I doing wrong? I know how to do this with Firestore in regular flutter, I can't understand what I need to do

Comment: I want to use a Streambuilder to return a ListView.builder that return a list of widgets based on snapshot of documents in a collection...

Comment: Hi @Chris if I understand correctly you want a streambuilder that returns a ListView.builder which returns widgets based on the snapshot. I put an example on github [Check the code out here](https://github.com/winckles/rooster/blob/master/chris). Let me know if this is getting close to what you're looking for

Comment: Hi Lorence, yes this is exactly what I'm trying to do. I understand the structure but the stream just isn't returning any data, or if it is it's not waiting for that data before the widget is built... So what I am getting is: "Something is wrong" .. no matter how I try to query, e.g. ```if(snapshot.hasData){}```  or whether I target a collection or document...

Comment: Feel like I'm going mad... :(

Comment: hm that is maddening indeed! What about your database rules? Do you have something like the following: 
`match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {

      allow read, write: if true;

    }`

Or what about your indexes?

Comment: Omg.. I just switched it to true from false and now it's working... Thank you so much, I completely forgot about the database rules

Comment: Hi again, I don't suppose you could help? I am able to target data by using a document as my stream but when using a collection I am unable to target info using the index... e.g. ```stream: Firestore.instance.collection('collection').snapshots()``` but when I try to do ```snapshot.data```, I am unable to add ```.documents``` or ```.docs```, and when I try ```snapshot.data[index]['data']``` I am not getting anything back... Also, I'm having problems with itemCount because I am getting a Future<int> back :(

Comment: have you tried using `.onSnapshot` instead of `.snapshots()`, so without the brackets?

Answer (score 1):

The `querySnapshot.docs` property returns a `List<DocumentSnapshot>`, while you need a `stream` for the `stream` property where each item on the stream is a list.

I've only needed this with the FlutterFire libraries for iOS/Android, but it should look something like this:

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getStream() async* {
  fb.firestore().collection("MyCollection").onSnapshot.listen((querySnapshot) {
    yield querySnapshot.docs;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you think of a reason why I'm seeing "Error: 'yield' isn't a type." on `yield querySnapshot.docs();`?

Comment: Hmmm.... I was hoping this would work for you, as I use it in some of my own tests here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59097364/209103

Comment: This should work:

Stream<...> stream = fb.firestore().collection("MyCollection").onSnapshot;
    await for (final snapshot in stream) {
              yield* snapshot.docs;
      }
    }