# Flutter Firestore Chat - Get recent conversations

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat app with Flutter. It works fine but I'm struggling to make a screen with previous conversations.
Something like this:

[image]

In my Firestore model I have collections and documents based on user ids... For example userA-userB. This collection contains documents with timestamp as a name. Inside the document there is content which I'd like to show.

[image]

As a backend for my app I use MySQL. Would it be best idea to store recent conversation data in MySQL. Like `userName, userAvatarUrl, date and content`. And then show it... Or is it possible to do directly from Firestore schema shown in the picture above?

Comment: you can do it if you combine documents

Comment: How do you mean "combine documents"?

Comment: you can combine documents like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061225/how-do-i-join-data-from-two-firestore-collections-in-flutter/59191174#59191174