# Covert a Query to display on a list tile Wigdet

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[![enter image description here][1]][1]please i want to covert this query snapshots to display on my list builder, i have been trying for hours to no avail, can some one please help am new to flutter and Firebase.

this the query, it runs fine when print to console

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) {//users query
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {//loop all users
   FirebaseFirestore.instance 
        .collection("orders")
        .doc(result.id)
        .collection("user_orders")
        .where('driversuid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) { //orders query
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {//loop all their orders
        print(result.data());
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I get this as the result of the query from the console.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOb3c.jpg

Comment: Please confirm one thing, is querySnapshot has data ?

Comment: I recommend checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061225/how-do-i-join-data-from-two-firestore-collections-in-flutter, where I asked for patterns for a similar join

Comment: @frank van i have tried checking your answers over there, i tried using nested builders but it does not work

Comment: If you think your nested builders should've worked, it's more likely we can help if you show what you tried with those.