# How to merge two Collection in firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Collection called `Channels` and a sub collection called `messages` , I want to get the data of every  Channels and also the data of sub collection `messages`:

```
 StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Channels')
            .where('particpants', arrayContains: UserInfoData.userID)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            final channesl = snapshot.data;
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Channels')
                .doc(channels[i][channelsID])  >>>> **here I want to get the messages belong to each channels**
                .collection('messages')
                .snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {},
          );
        },
      )
```

how I can  get the channelsID of every channels ?

I wish my question is clear

[image]

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but do check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061225/how-do-i-join-data-from-two-firestore-collections-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not possible in a single query.

Your best option is to make one query for Channels, then another [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) for messages.  The collection group query will give you all documents in all subcollections with the same name.  You will need to manually merge each document from messages with the Channel it came from by looking at the path of the document (or adding more data to each message to indicate which Channel it's related to.