# How to get data of a document from another collection having its document id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hello im new to firebase.

I have 3 collections

Users:
- userid

Providers:
- Providerid
- providerName
- providerEmail

FavoriteProvider:
- docId(userId+providerId)
- userId
- providerId

So, i have succeed put a favorite provider for a user and the user can have many favorite providers.

But how to get a stream list of favorite providers of that user in one list.

I tried using this code

```
Stream<List<SerProviders>> get favoriteProviders{
   favoriteProvidersCollectionRef.where('userId', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots.map(providerListfromsnapshot)
}
```

The function `providerListfromssnapshot` returns a list of providers according to model a created in flutter.

```
List<SerProvider> providerListfromssnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
Return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
   Var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
Return SerProvider(
  ProviderId: doc.id,
  ProviderName: data['providerName'] 
);}).toList();
}
```

But no idea how to complete.

I need the data of the provider (id and name) in that stream.

Anyone help me plzzz

Comment: It looks like you're trying to [join data from two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061225/how-do-i-join-data-from-two-firestore-collections-in-flutter). I'd specifically have a look at this answer with a [custom stream builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59097364/209103), or the answer [using RxDart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191174/209103).

Comment: i really can't understand the answer , can u answer my question according to my code?