# How can I connect fields in different collection and store in a single collection in firebase - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a collection of bookings which contains "UserID", "restaurantID" & a "bookingID". I am storing it in a collection "Bookings". What I want here is show the collection "Bookings" in the field(bookings) of my "Users" collection and "restaurant" collection according to the userID & restaurantID.

**Restaurant and User Collection are pretty much the same.

Please help me with a solution to this. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, what did you try? Can you share your code?

Comment: I actually don't understand how to do it.. I have just stored the data in firebase as a new collection. I want that collection to be used as a field in my restaurant and user collection.

Comment: I believe you wanted to do join equivalent in firebase, you can store reference of another document in another collection in any collection instead of keeping copies of data.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I join data from two Firestore collections in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061225/how-do-i-join-data-from-two-firestore-collections-in-flutter)