# I want to add dynamic data from multiple firebase collections to a pdf in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:resume_builder/text_design_education.dart';
import 'package:resume_builder/text_design_experience.dart';
import 'package:resume_builder/text_design_objective.dart';
import 'package:resume_builder/text_design_personal.dart';
import 'package:resume_builder/text_design_skills.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'package:resume_builder/text_design_personal.dart';

class ResumeProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  ResumeProfile({super.key, required this.resumeid});
  var resumeid;

  @override
  State<ResumeProfile> createState() => _ResumeProfileState();
}

class _ResumeProfileState extends State<ResumeProfile> {
  final authencatedUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text('Resume'),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.more_vert,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('userdetails')
                  .where("userId", isEqualTo: currentUser.currentUser!.uid)
                  .where('resumeid', isEqualTo: widget.resumeid)
                  .get(),
              builder: (ctx, Snapshots) {
                if (Snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (!Snapshots.hasData || Snapshots.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text('Please Add Details'),
                  );
                }
                if (Snapshots.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text('Something went wrong'),
                  );
                }
                final resumedata = Snapshots.data!.docs;

                print('data: ${Snapshots.data!.docs}');
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

                    // reverse: true,
                    itemCount: resumedata.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final resumeUser = resumedata[index].data();
                      print('data 1: ${resumedata[index].data()}');

                      final doc = pw.Document();

                      doc.addPage(
                        pw.MultiPage(
                            pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
                            build: (pw.Context context) {
                              return <pw.Widget>[
                                pw.Row(
                                  children: [
                                    pw.SizedBox(
                                      width: 20,
                                    ),
                                    pw.Container(
                                      width: 60,
                                    ),
                                    pw.SizedBox(
                                      width: 20,
                                    ),
                                    pw.Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        pw.Text(
                                          '${resumeUser['name']}',
                                        ),
                                        pw.Text('${resumeUser['address']}'),
                                        pw.Text('${resumeUser['email']}'),
                                        pw.Text('${resumeUser['phone']}'),
                                       
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ];
                            }),
                      );
Printing.layoutPdf(
                          onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => doc.save());

                      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        setState(() {});
                      });
});
              },
            ),
 ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am getting single collection data from firebase to a pdf but at the same time I want other collection data to the same pdf, I am getting here only personal info of user but I want to display educational details, experience details etc. which are in different collection in firebase please help me to find out solution ,your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How about using another `FutureBuilder` for the data from the second collection? Also see my questoin and the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59061225/209103

Comment: Or maybe you want to look at having a less normalized schema? Should the Education and Experience details (and other data) actually be on the user's info document?  Firestore is NoSQL....avoid normalizing your data too much.  You want to avoid doing "JOINs" as they are sub-optimal.  Embrace data DE-normalization!  https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/designing-firestore-collections-documents (a blog post on designing a Firestore database model)

Comment: @GregFenton Yes I want to create the pdf with other details like education details, experience details etc. on a single pdf file and it could be multiple educations or experiences inside these collections.

Comment: @GregFenton problems I am facing are  
1. I am getting firebase data inside Future Builder and then i am passing the value to the doc.addpage then the printing option for saving the pdf but futurebuilder only getting one collection at a time and if i put another futurebuilder after first futurebuilder then its very difficult to create pdf for both the futurebuilder data

Comment: @GregFenton 2. If I add multiple education of the user then the pdf displays only single education if filtered from where query like this (FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('education').where("userId", isEqualTo: currentUser.currentUser!.uid).where('resumeid', isEqualTo: widget.resumeid).get(),)

Is there any other option(idea) for getting the needed results.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I already tried another future builder but doc.addpage is inside first futurebuilder and i need to add several collections of current user data in pdf suppose if i put another doc.addpage to second futurebuilder then another pdf file will be created after first and both have different data from different collections,and i need several collections on single pdf and I dont want to join collections using rxdart because its complex,the method you told there is also could not be applicable,could you help me please by another solution?

Comment: The page I linked has multiple answer. Whenever I need data from multiple collections, use one of them. Typically these days, I'd use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59097364/209103 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162226/209103

Comment: When I am mentioning a single document, I mean a record in the Firestore database. I am suggesting that you look to combining information about a user into a single user document rather than having to read multiple independent documents. Consider reading the article I linked to above.