# Is it possible to combine Firestore streams in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter app, I'm using this Firestore Stream :

```
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> requestsClosedOrPending = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(clients)
      .where('isOpened', isEqualTo: false)
      .where('isPending', isEqualTo: true)
      .snapshots();
```

So to include the documents in the stream, the document needs to have the field `isOpened = false` AND `isPending = true`.

But what I want is to have an OR statement instead : to include the documents in the stream, the document should have the field `isOpened = false` OR `isPending = true`. Is it possible ?

Also, I'm using this stream in a StreamBuilder :

```
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> requestsStream(Future triggerAnalytics) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: requestsClosedOrPending,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              // Rest of the code..//
```

Maybe I should add the or statement in the StreamBuilder itself ? I'm opened to any suggestion that could combine the streams.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore nowadays supports having OR conditions in a query, but you got the syntax wrong. Your requirement would translate to something like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(clients)
    .where(
      Filter.or(
        Filter('isOpened', isEqualTo: false),
        Filter('isPending', isEqualTo: true)
      )
    )
```

Also see the Firestore documentation on [using an OR condition in a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_14).

---

If you ever find a case where you **do** need to combine multiple streams, have a look at [How do I join data from two Firestore collections in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061225/how-do-i-join-data-from-two-firestore-collections-in-flutter)